# How to integrate Google App Engine to an existing web application?

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications

I am new to Google App Engine, I have an existing web application and now I need to integrate that with Google App Engine for  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/receiving purpose, how to do that?

Comment: -1 We have no idea what your existing app does or how you'd like to integrate that.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to write your appengine application with a RPC service

http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2011/04/introducing-protorpc-for-writing-app.html